# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am not experienced in flutter but been doing it for a while. My current project is using firebase so I'm using flutterfire package and it has to be my worst nightmare so far. Build fail upon build fail. Note IOS is working though. The recent is this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_crashlytics:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':firebase_crashlytics:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:.
     Required by:
         project :firebase_crashlytics

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
        }
    }
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' &&
                    !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tendo.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

rootProject.ext {
  set('FlutterFire', [
    FirebaseSDKVersion: '21.1.0'
  ])
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **implement** the **dependencies** in app-level gradle file `app/build.gradle`

```
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
```

The **dependencies** section should look like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
}
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I also would like to recommend you to follow this [Initialize Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android#initialize-crashlytics) to specific dependencies setup for Java / Kotlin

Comment: I tried it and I just did this and still same build failure and same message :(

Comment: I've update the code. Once try to update in your code. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the version in android/build.gradle:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: I have done that over and over the current version you are seeing is what i got from the official doc of firebase. I know this version is from the docs from fluttterfire. Yet still i tried your answer and still build fail :(

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to check the use of the **setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled**, because if you disabled the crash collection setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false) and then if later you want to enable it, just commenting out the above line DOES NOT automatically start the collection process if the app has already been installed with 'false' flag before, so setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true) needs to be explicitly called again.

But for me the problem was exactly in **setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)**, I called it every start, so I comment it out, and error disappeared.